# Basic question about relation between algebraic k-theory and group cohomology

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, group-cohomology, algebraic-k-theory

In the wikapedia article on group cohomology (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology#Algebraic_K-theory_and_homology_of_linear_groups) , there is a short section on how it relates to group cohomology, via the plus construction.

First, is there an introductory source that I could read about this? (I haven't studied much group cohomology, and can't find anything about it in Wiebel or Quillen's paper)

Second, it is not even clear to me how it relates. Is there some equality between the two?

Thank you!

Comment: You might find Tom Goodwillie and Dustin Clausen's answer on the following link helpful: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121340/plus-construction-considerations/121368#121368

Comment: Thank you! So in the case of $GL(R)$, does $H^*(BGL(R) ) = H^*(GL(R))$? (first is singular, second is group)

Comment: User109249, what you said is true. It is one way of defining group cohomology.