# The third (co)homology group

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology

I need to prove that the third (co)homology group of a certain finitely presented group is not finitely generated. The group is not an amalgamated product or an HNN extension, and it does not act nicely on a CAT(0) cube complex. It does have torsion and its presentation is  very non-aspherical. What do I do? That is what are the methods of proving it?

Comment: I keep looking at this question, thinking "Surely the OP has tried Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence methods," but you didn't mention trying that, and nobody else has asked--so I apologize for suggesting something very naive, but have you looked for filtrations of your group by normal subgroups, such that you have some cohomological understanding of the filtration quotients? It may be possible to use the LHSSS of each resulting group extension, iteratively, to get some kind of hold on H^3 of your group. Sorry again for suggesting something more naive than what you already mentioned :/

Comment: The group does not have a natural filtraton, unfortunately.

Comment: With which coefficients?  The trivial module $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Do you know $H_1$ and $H_2$?

Comment: Oh, that's a good point: if H_2 of the group (i.e., its Schur multiplier) turns out to be sufficiently "interesting," you can automatically get that H^3 of the group is huge. For example, if H_2(G; Z) is Q, then the universal coefficient sequence gives you a copy of Ext^1_Z(Q, Z) inside H^3(G; Z), so H^3(G; Z) is uncountable, so certainly not finitely generated.

Comment: @aaaaaaaaaa : According to the question the group is finitely presented, so the second homology $H_2(G,\mathbb{Z})$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module. In particular $H_2 \neq \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @SteffenKionke: Please forgive me if I have misunderstood, but it seems to me that finitely generated groups do not necessarily have finitely generated Schur multipliers. Noetherian groups do, by Hopf's formula for the Schur multiplier, but a non-Noetherian finitely generated group may have non-finitely-generated Schur multiplier. My understanding is that Tarski monsters are examples: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219820/schur-multiplier-of-tarski-monsters/297309 One coauthors on the paper cited there is the OP on the present question, so perhaps such examples are relevant here.

Comment: @aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa — yes, but we are told that the group is finitely *presented*, which is much stronger than finitely generated.

Comment: In general, lacunary hyperbolic groups indeed have infinitely generated Schur multiplyers. This includes Tarski monsters of unbounded exponents. But these are not finitely presented.

Comment: I'd say best call here would be using homological shifts (concretely, $H_*(F/R, R_{ab}) = H_{*+1}(F/R, \Delta) = H_{*+2}(F/R, \Bbb Z)$) and trying some explicit computations with Lyndon's partial resolvent. This approach is, of course, much better suited for proving that some homology _is_ finitely generated, but may help anyway.

Comment: Next to impossible for me to figure out whether it is feasible but you might try to look at the [$+$-construction](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121340/plus-construction-considerations/121351#121351) of the classifying space of your group - it has the same homology and usually is a much nicer space